# different ulimit when I run /bin/sh -c

Tags: shell, ulimit

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ /bin/sh -c ulimit -n
unlimited
```

Even if I specify the shell I am using:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ /bin/bash -c ulimit -n
unlimited
```

Why is ulimit not giving me the same value?

Comment: Maybe you set the soft ulimit in the shell startup file. You can add -x to see all commands the shell would execute on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you're running `ulimit` without arguments. The `-n` is not part of the command being executed, and will instead become `$0`. The thing that's `unlimited` is therefore the max file size

Compare the output of:

```
bash -c 'echo hello'  # says hello
bash -c echo hello    # blank line
```

and then run:

```
bash -c 'ulimit -n'
```